# Quick proof clarification: Show 1 dimensional manifold is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or a circle

Tags: manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

I am trying to see it in the case where we just have to open sets $U,V$ that cover the connected manifold $M$, each of which is homeomorphic to the real line.

I know that the answer depends on the number of connected components of the intersection. I just really need an aclaration with a proof for the case where we have two (in which case is homemorphic to a circle) connected components. I am following this nice [proof](https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/igt/eiserm/lehre/2014/Topologie/Gale%20-%201-manifolds.pdf).

And the part I am stucked with is specifically in proposition 2, part c. How could we prove the map is an homeomorphisms? And why again is the union of $U$ and $V$ compact? Thanks a lot.

Edit: I am thinking about how just because $h_1=f \circ \phi$ and $h_2=g \circ \psi$ are homeomorphisms in their respective images, that they dont intersect and cover the whole square, then doesn't follow that the function $\eta$ is an homeomorphism by the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am thinking about how just because $h_1 = f \circ \phi$ and $h_2 = g \circ  \psi$ are homeomorphisms in their respective images, that they dont intersect and cover the whole square, then doesn't follow that the function $\eta$ is an homeomorphism by the pasting lemma?

Yes, $\eta$ is constructed by pasting, so you can appeal to the pasting lemma. But as you noted, we have some open sets and some closed sets, which doesn't satisfy the lemma. Notice the proof outline defines $f$ on $[0,1]$, even though the image of $\phi$ is just $(0,1)$. Define $\tilde \phi : \bar U \to [0,1]$ as a continuous extension of $\phi$ as follows. For $x \in U$, $\tilde \phi(x) = \phi(x)$. For any point $x$ on the boundary of $U$, we have an infinite sequence in $U$ which converges to $x$. $\phi$ maps this sequence to an infinite sequence in $(0,1)$, which must converge to either $0$ or $1$. So define $\tilde \phi(x) = \psi^{-1}(b)$ if the mapped sequence converges to $0$, or $\tilde \phi(x) = \psi^{-1}(b')$ if the mapped sequence converges to $1$; this is independent of the original sequence converging to $x$. Now $\eta$ agrees with $f \circ \tilde \phi$ on $\bar U$, and $f \circ \tilde \phi$ and its inverse are continuous, so the pasting lemma does apply using the two closed sets $\bar U$ and $V - U$.

So $\eta$ is a homeomorphism between $U \cup V$ and the unit square.

> And why again is the union of $U$ and $V$ compact?

If we've shown that $\eta$ is a bijection between $U \cup V$ and the unit square, and that $\eta^{-1}$ is continuous, then for any open set $S \subseteq U \cup V$, $\eta(S)$ is open in the unit square's topology. The unit square is compact. So if $\mathcal{O}$ is any open cover of $U \cup V$...

The big catch is that although $\eta$ has been defined for points in $U \cup V$, we're asked to show its domain is actually all of the manifold $X$. We can show $U \cup V = X$ using connectedness of $X$.

Take any $p \in X$, and let $\sigma: [0,1] \to X$ be a continuous path with $\sigma(0) = p$, $\sigma(1) \in U \cup V$. Then the set $\sigma^{-1}(U \cup V)$ is not empty, is open in $[0,1]$ since $\sigma$ is continuous, and is compact, therefore closed. But the only subsets of $[0,1]$ which are both open and closed are the empty set and the entire $[0,1]$, so $\sigma^{-1}(U \cup V)$ must be $[0,1]$, meaning $\sigma(0) = p \in U \cup V$, so every point of $X$ is in $U \cup V$ and $U \cup V = X$.

Can you finish from those hints?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some doubts however:
Why do we need to prove it is defined for $X$ again if $X=U \cup V$? Also I have read in Wiki that for the pasting lemma we need both of the sets to be open. But if $U$ is  open and $V-U=X-U$ then $V-U$ is closed, so I am not sure if we can use. So to prove the homeomorphism we need to focus on the continuity properties of the function, and I do not see how what you wrote is giving me hints on it. Thanks again.

Comment: Proving that $X=U \cup V$ is how we prove that the domain of $\eta$ is all of $X$. And sorry, right, the pasting lemma as usually stated doesn't apply.

Comment: I see. But if we prove that $X=U \cup V$ we still need to show that the map is continuous and open. How would it follow from this?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your update. Just to check: you meant "Now $\eta$ agrees with $f \circ \tilde{\phi}$ on $\tilde{U}$)..." right? and also if the sequence converges to 0 we want it to the converge of $b$ and not $b'$ don't we?
I got the argument that showed the compactness of $U \cup V$ thanks. But in the last part, I do not see where we are going with the proof. We want that $U \cup V \subset X$ to conclude it.

Comment: Correct for both. Made the corrections, and filled out the last paragraph more.

Comment: Dear @aschepler thank you once more. Now it all looks good to me except on the last part. It seems to me that you are proving that $X \subset U \cup V$: "so every point of $X$ is in $U \cup V$...". But we already know this since it is a cover. And the fact that $X$ is path connected lets you connect points in $X$, but you are already connecting points in the union of $U$ and $V$, even though we still do not know if this point lies in $X$ already. Thanks.

Comment: The problem statement doesn't say $\{ U, V \}$ is a cover, just that they are two open sets with two intersection components. Which is enough to prove that they do in fact cover $X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the discussion.

Comment: I figured out it does not really make sense how we defined the extension, since it has to map to a real number, but you defined it so that it maps to some element of the manifold ;(